# How do I link form_tag path to a seeded database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently building a recipe site.

I have a model *hbdatabase* which contains an ingredient list with two attributes, name and i_id. I have already seeded a database for this model, and it has 30,000+ ingredient entries.

When respondents create a new recipe, I want them to be able to select ingredients from this database via a dropdown list. I have tried using form_tag, but I'm not sure what path to include for them to access this database. No entries come up when I type into the search bar.

**Controller:**

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
    def new
    @recipe = current_user.recipes.new
    @hbdatabase=Hbdatabase.all
    if params[:search]
        @hbdatabase=Hbdatabase.search(params[:search])
    else 
        @hbdatabase=Hbdatabase.all
    end
end
```

**Model**

```
class Hbdatabase < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :name

    def self.search(search)
        if search
            where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
        else
            all
        end
    end
end
```

**Views > Layouts > Recipes > New.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag(new_recipe_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
<p>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I right understand, you didn't get ingredients after click on "Search" button? How do you output them?